# Bubble sort loop, changes one number to 0

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm pretty new to programming. As the title says, I've wrote simple bubble sort code. There are 3 functions, one that takes numbers from user, second prints them, and there's this 3rd one, that bubble sorts numbers. I've forced it to sort numbers at least, but it's still turning one number to 0, and I don't have any idea.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void acquire_num();
void print_num();
void sort_bubble();

int numbers[5];


int main()
{
    acquire_num();
    print_num();
    sort_bubble();
    print_num();
}

void acquire_num()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Write " << i+1 << " number: ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
}

void print_num()
{
    cout << "Your numbers are:";

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << numbers[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void sort_bubble()
{
    int indicator;
    int store;

    do
    {
        indicator = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
            {
                indicator = indicator+1;
                store = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
                numbers[i+1] = store;
            }
        }
    }
    while(indicator != 0);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Will look at this in seconds. Thanks!

Comment: A bubble sort that can sort only the array `int numbers[5]:`is useless.

Comment: @manni66 it's supposed to work as a learning tool ;-;

Comment: _t's supposed to work as a learning tool_ that's not a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop inside `sort_bubble`, where `i` goes from `0` to `4`, you use `numbers[i+1]` which at the end will be `numbers[5]` which is an invalid number of the array. Make the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has **5** elements.

Comparing the current element with the next, your sorting loop need to run from **0** to  **3**, because with 4 it would be undefined behavior to access the next element because it's outside of the array.